# Dice rolling program using set and get methods in Java

Tags: java, random

I am trying to write a program that creates two objects /instances of a class (Dice) to simulate a pair of dice. The program should simulate the rolling of the 2 dice and display their values using the OutputDice method.

The **Value** field holds the value of the dice. The **SetValue** method stores a value in the Value field.The **GetValue** method returns the value of the dice. The **Roll** method that generates a random number in the range of 1 through 6 for the value of the die. The **OutputDice** method output the value of the dice as text.

I realize that the following code is horribly incomplete but I cannot figure out how to encapsulate the random function into the output.

My two classes are as follows:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Dice {

    private int Value;

    public void setValue(int diceValue) {
           Value = diceValue;
    }

    public int getValue() {
           return Value;
    }

    public void roll() {
        //I am not sure how to structure this section
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DiceRollOutput {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        String firstDie;
        String secondDie;
        int firstNumber;
        int secondNumber;

        Scanner diceRoll = new Scanner(System.in);

        Random Value = new Random();

        firstNumber = Value.nextInt(6)+1;
        secondNumber = Value.nextInt(6)+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe more details of your classes and what is the question exactly.

Comment: //I am not sure how to structure this section . For generating random dice values you can use Random Class in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate the random integers in the Dice class instead of the main method.

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dice {

    private int value;

    public void setValue(int diceValue) {
           value = diceValue;
    }

    public int getValue() {
           return value;
    }

    public void roll() {
        //I am not sure how to structure this section
        Random rand = new Random();
        value = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
    }
}

public class DiceRollOutput {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Dice firstDie = new Dice();
        Dice secondDie = new Dice();

        firstDie.roll();
        secondDie.roll();


        System.out.println("Dice 1: "+ firstDie.getValue());
        System.out.println("Dice 2: "+ secondDie.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Thanks uzr that got me on the right track and solved the question I was asking!